# Order the min over ndarrays by keeping information about the original indexes

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Consider having a `numpy.ndarray` D1 with shape `(10,N,M)`.
I would like to build a new ndarray O1 with shape `(N*M,3)`. such that:

- each element is a triplet that identifies the index of an element over D1
- the indexes are sorted according to their value of the corresponding fields in D1
- for each `0≤i≤N`, `0≤j≤M` only the minimum element over the 10 dimensions is considered.

Let's consider a small example with 2 instead of 10 and the current approach that partially achieves my goal:

```
>>> d1 = np.random.randint(20, size=2*3*3).reshape(2,3,3)

array([[[ 2,  6, 18],
        [18, 18, 10],
        [ 2,  3,  1]],

        [[11,  3, 14],
        [12, 14, 18],
        [ 6,  8, 19]]])

>>> d2 = np.amin(d1, axis=0)

array([[ 2,  3, 14],
       [12, 14, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  1]])

>>> o1 = np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(d2.ravel()), d2.shape))

array([[[2, 2],
        [0, 0],
        [2, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 0],
        [0, 2],
        [1, 1]]])
```

In this way, I'm getting the minimum indexes over the elements with respects to the 2 dimension but I'm loosing the information about the initial indexes in D1.

The expected output should be in this case:

```
array([[[0, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 2, 1],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 2],
        [1, 1, 1]]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A structured array is a handy way to work with the indices and minimum values at the same time:

```
M, N = d1.shape[1:]
mi, ni = np.ogrid[:M, :N]
data = np.empty((M, N), [('coords', np.intp, 3), ('min', d1.dtype)])
data['coords'][..., 0] = mi
data['coords'][..., 1] = ni
data['coords'][..., 2] = np.argmin(d1, axis=0)
data['min'] = np.min(d1, axis=0)

data = data.ravel()  # collapse (M, N) to (M*N,)
data_sorted = data[np.argsort(data['min'])]
o1 = data_sorted['coords']
```

But you can also get there easily from your code:

```
d2 = np.min(d1, axis=0)
arg_d2 = np.argmin(d1, axis=0)
order = np.argsort(d2.ravel())
mi, ni = np.unravel_index(order, d2.shape)
o1 = np.stack((mi, ni, arg_d2.ravel()[order]), axis=-1)  # dstack but faster
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However in the second method `arg_d2[order]` seems lo lead to an `IndexError`.

Comment: @abc: Fixed, I think